# Ways to get around the limiting default terrain shaders in Unity

Tags: unity, shaders, terrain

I am trying to use the Toon Rim Light shader for Unity however there are a few problems when trying to use any custom shaders for a terrain in Unity. The most well known is of course, that all textures immediately become a blurry mess and ruins the look. The other issue is that all shading on the terrain ceases to be, and causes it to not cast shadows for both nature objects as well as characters.

I have researched methods for circumventing this problem, however all sources for troubleshooting have been inadequate in providing enough details or steps in correcting the issue and I am left to turn here for a possible better breakdown of the processes and coding involved in achieving the effect that I desire.

Thank you in advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can nobody help me on this issue?